# What is the use of hello_view.ex in Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I was reading the 'Programming Phoenix' book to create my first MVC simple routing project. In the book, it says to create a 'hello_view.ex', and it's under the view section in MVC. But there is already a view in templates. This feels very confusing.

Also, they told me to put hello_world.html inside 'hello' folder in templates. Can I change this folder name? Why can't I rename it? In 'hello_controller.ex', it says 'hello_world.html', not 'hello/hello_world.html'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoenix views aren't HTML templates with embedded programming language like `html.erb`, but the names are similar to the ones in Django, where `view` means code for displaying data and `template` means actual HTML with embedded Elixir code (and they have extension `eex`). 
According to the official guide for Phoenix Framework, short info about views:

> They also act as a presentation layer for raw data from the controller, preparing it for use in a template. Functions which perform this transformation should go in a view.

Check this out:

Ruby on Rails flow:

`router.rb -> Controller (-> Model) -> view in html.erb`

Django flow:

`urls.py -> View (act like Controller) -> Template`

Phoenix flow:

`endpoint (in lib) -> router (in web) -> Controller -> View -> Template`

The Phoenix flow seems to be longer, but it's not. The biggest advantage for you:

## You have explicit control over the middleware!

Remember that- framework does the magic for you, but explicitly. You exactly see what macros and other stuff are called.

## Edit

Check out the stuff that's imported when using `use` in your code.

In your controller you're using `Phoenix.Controller` stuff, which provides you `render` function.

You call `render` with conn, template and assigns parameters. In `deps/phoenix/lib/phoenix/controller.ex` you have this `render`
function stored and in the private function `do_render` line:

```
view = Map.get(conn.private, :phoenix_view) ||
        raise "a view module was not specified, set one with put_view/2"
```

Gets your View name from the current connection.

And few lines later uses it:

```
Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata(view, template, Map.put(conn.assigns, :conn, conn))
```

This call uses internally `render` in `deps/phoenix/lib/phoenix/view.ex`
and then `render_within`, but the name of the folder is set in `__using__`

```
use Phoenix.Template, Phoenix.View.__template_options__(__MODULE__, unquote(opts))
```

which calls `__template__options` where following lines are placed:

```
    module
    |> Module.split()
    |> Enum.take(1)
    |> Module.concat()
```

which does the `Hello` from `Hello.PageView` or whatever the name is.

## Edit2

About changing default view in controller (info from Phoenix documentation):

> By default, Controllers render templates in a view with a similar name
>   to the   controller. For example, `MyApp.UserController` will render
>   templates inside   the `MyApp.UserView`. This information can be
>   changed any time by using   `render/3`, `render/4` or the `put_view/2`
>   function:

```
  def show(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, MyApp.SpecialView, :show, message: "Hello")
  end

  def show(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_view(MyApp.SpecialView)
    |> render(:show, message: "Hello")
  end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. But can you tell me how does it know that 'hello_world.html' is inside 'hello' folder? I couldn't see any code that's say so. I've uploaded a screenshot of the project

Comment: I first typed the comment ;)

Comment: Ok. I tried changing the name of the folder to 'something'. and Hello.HelloView to Something.HelloView. But it was not working

Comment: Use `put_view` to change default view in controller or put this in `render`. I edited my answer again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126718/discussion-between-patnowak-and-gijo-varghese).